# Which fonts gets downloaded if the browser supports both versions?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

Say I have 2 versions of font customFont1.woff2 and customFont1.woff.  I put the woff 2 version first and then the woff version 2nd in font declaration file. The browser supports **both** font formats. Does both of the fonts get downloaded or does it only download woff2 and then ignore the woff version or it downloads the other version of fonts too, to check the best format font to avoid FOIT?

Answer (score 1):

according to https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts-3/#descdef-src:

> This descriptor specifies the resource containing font data. It is required for the @font-face rule to be valid. Its value is a prioritized, comma-separated list of external references or locally-installed font face names. When a font is needed the user agent iterates over the set of references listed, using the first one it can successfully activate.

Comment: So if the first one is successfully activated then it does not iterates over others formats of fonts? That is what I am understanding ver article.

Comment: that's what i understand as well

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you for pointing that out.